# xslt replace pattern with <br/>

Tags: regex, replace, xslt-2.0

Original Input:

> class signup. Expires 09/16/2013.

Desired Output:

```
class signup.<br />Expires 09/16/2013.
```

Actual result:

```
class signup <br />. Expires 09/16/2013.
```

Attempted code:

```
<xsl:analyze-string select="$fdesc" regex="[.]\s+\w+">
    <xsl:matching-substring>
        <br/> <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </xsl:matching-substring>
    <xsl:non-matching-substring>
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </xsl:non-matching-substring>
</xsl:analyze-string>
```

Comment: I have edited my answer because it had an error, my mistake sorry for that, please check edit.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your original code is that the matching substring is equal to `. Expires` and you are inserting `<br/>` just before that.

I modified that so the matching substring is now `class signup` and I am inserting `<br />` after that immediately.

Here is my attempt:

```
<xsl:analyze-string select="$fdesc" regex="[^.]+">
    <xsl:matching-substring>
        <xsl:value-of select="."/><br/> 
    </xsl:matching-substring>

    <xsl:non-matching-substring>
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </xsl:non-matching-substring>
</xsl:analyze-string>
```

Please let me know of any problems.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it with ....

```
            <span class="ccb_form_description">
                <!-- xsl:value-of select="$fdesc" / -->
                <xsl:analyze-string select="$fdesc" regex="([.])(\s+)(\w+)">
                    <xsl:matching-substring>
                        <xsl:value-of select="regex-group(1)"/>
                        <br/>
                        <xsl:value-of select="regex-group(3)"/>
                    </xsl:matching-substring>
                    <xsl:non-matching-substring>
                        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                    </xsl:non-matching-substring>
                </xsl:analyze-string>
            </span>
```

this gives me:

```
class signup.<br>Expires 09/16/2013.
```

...with no spaces and less chance of adding br tags when it is just one sentence that ends with a .